# How can I find replacement part for Mongoose scooter?

Tags: repair, bolt, kick-scooter

My daughter broke the quick release hinge bolt (I have no idea what to call it) on her Mongoose scooter.

[image]

[image]

Where can I go to find a replacement part or at a minimum, what is it called?

Comment: Great photos thank you.  How did the bolt break in the first place?  I can't see a crack but I do see scoring, possibly the scooter got folded up repeatedly?   Some lubrication could have minimised damage over time.

Comment: @Criggie that is the bolt of another scooter for a more conservative child 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a quick release seatpost binder

You might have a bicycle with one on it you could use to test the fit.
[image]
Googling "bicycle seatpost quick release M6 × 65mm" gets results
Here's one on [ebay as an example](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Alloy-Bicycle-Seat-Post-Quick-Release-50mm-60mm-65mm-Bikes/392258829904?hash=item5b5472be50:m:mhgkf3AkhuvD3UZNFWdW-pA) (not a recommendation)

Or, you might be able to find a metric bolt with the correct thread down at the hardware store along with appropriate washers. Tighten it with a wrench rather than have a quick release lever as a temporary fix.

Comment: David D, that’s the best I’ve been able to find as well. The shaft of the bolt gets quite a bit of stress, so I probably need to go to the hardware store for a bolt and washers that will hold up better.

Comment: @David a hardware store bolt would be even worse - they tend to be low grade steel.  Ideally you'd want a harder bolt but that will wear the aluminium frame of the scooter.   <br>  ALSO I suspect your mini-David tends to fold up the scooter a lot, so a non-QR one will be annoying for her.   I'd get new binder bolts for each scooter now, and put the pictured "okay" one aside as a temp spare.  Also, add this bolt to your periodic maintenance and eyeball it ~monthly to look for wear.

Comment: @Criggie my local hardware store has a variety of steel grades to choose from. My thought was that it might be a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the manual
It's a spring release button with a quick release lever
https://p.widencdn.net/xsfu1n/Mongoose-Folding-Scooter-Manual-D10-052617